# php - printing keys with embedded function

Tags: php, printing, foreach

I need help figuring out these php print (echo) statements and where to place them. I have an embedded function 'strotime' that is transforming time (column 'StartTime') to a format, but I cannot get it to print out correctly. No errors, just no changes or use of the function.

Can someone help me figure out where to place this properly in this foreach loop? 
(as you can see, i placed at beginning and tried an if statment too..but no luck). Thanks for
your help.

```
$keys = array('Server', 'Target','Logdate','Set','StartTime', 'Length','Size','Status');
echo '<table><tr>';
foreach ($keys as $column)
   echo '<th>' . $column . '</th>';
    echo '</tr>';

foreach ($data as $row){
   echo '<tr>';
     foreach ($keys as $column)
      //if ($column == 'StartTime') {
      // echo '<td>' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($row[$column])) . '</td>';
        if (isset($row[$column])){
          echo '<td>' . $row[$column] . '</td>';
        } elseif ($column =='StartTime') {
          echo '<td>' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($row[$column])) . '</td>';
        } elseif ($column == 'Status') {
          echo '<td> Check for Errors </td>';
        } else {
          echo '<td> </td>';
        }
      //}
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Your function is misspelled (`strotime` instead of `strtotime`). And what does `$data` contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the beginning if `foreach ($data as $row){` loop, do this:

```
 $row['StartTime'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($row['StartTime']));
```

And then display it like any other column.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (isset($row[$column])) {
```

to

```
if (isset($row[$column]) && $column != "StartTime") {
```

and by the way: you're missing the `</tr>` tags.